# Solving $(\cos{x}+3)(\cos{x}-1)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I started with this equation
$$2\cos{x}-2=\sin^2{x} \tag{1}$$

and took the following steps to solve it (for radians):

$$\begin{align}
2\cos{x}-2=1-\cos^2{x} \tag{2} \\    
2\cos{x}-2+\cos^2{x}-1=0 \tag{3} \\    
\cos^2{x}+2\cos{x}-3=0 \tag{4} \\    
(\cos{x}+3)(\cos{x}-1)=0 \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

> I get these two factors in $(5)$, but the $(\cos{x}+3)$ factor is undefined, so I don't know how to solve this for real.

I know the answer is either $0$ or $2\pi$, but I only found that out through trial-and-error, not algebraically.

Comment: It just means that there are no real solutions for that factor. Kind of like $(x^2 + 4)(x-1) = 0$, no real solutions for the first factor.

Answer (score 3):

$$(\cos x+3)(\cos x -1)=0\iff \cos x =-3\,\textbf{ or }\,\cos x =1$$

You have correctly observed that there is no $x\in\mathbb{R}$ for which $\cos x=-3$, so the only option is if $\cos x=1$. This occurs when $x=2\pi n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.